# Extracting XML nodes into Hive table using Xpath

Tags: xml, hadoop, xpath, hive

We have a Hive table where one of the string columns contains XML.  To simplify, assume that the table is:

```
DataTable
key: string
xml: string
```

and that the xml is in the format:

```
<xml>
    <entity>
        <property type="alpha">123</property>
        <property type="beta">abc</property>
        <property type="delta">...</property>
    </entity>
    <entity>
        <property type="alpha">321</property>
        <property type="beta">cba</property>
        <property type="delta">---</property>
    </entity>
</xml>
```

with 0..N entity nodes.

I'd like to transform this data into a new Hive table with the following format:

```
TransformedTable
key: string
alpha: string
beta: string
delta: string
```

but I'm finding it difficult.  I'm pretty new to Hive, but am thinking something like this should be right up it's alley.

The following questions are related:

- [Parsing a nested XML string from a Hive table using PIG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36240294/parsing-a-nested-xml-string-from-a-hive-table-using-pig)
- [Parse repeating XML tags in Hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41462410/parse-repeating-xml-tags-in-hive)

but don't have answers.  And this question has a related answer:

- [Exception while using lateral view in Hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41481582/exception-while-using-lateral-view-in-hive)

but I don't think I can use the xml SerDe in this case.  Through that research, I've tried things like this:

```
select key, 
       xpath(xml, 'xml/entity/property[@type="alpha"]/text()')) as alpha,
       xpath(xml, 'xml/entity/property[@type="beta"]/text()')) as beta,
       xpath(xml, 'xml/entity/property[@type="delta"]/text()')) as delta
  from DataTable
```

but that results in this:

```
key1    ["123", "321"]    ["abc", "cba"]    ["...", "---"]
key2    ["123", "321"]    ["abc", "cba"]    ["...", "---"]
```

instead of what I'd really like:

```
key1    123    abc    ...
key1    321    cba    ---
key2    123    abc    ...
key2    321    cba    ---
```

Thanks for taking the time to read this, and I'd appreciate any ideas you can give me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array-based data can be "joined" into a relation using [`LATERAL VIEW`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+LateralView) in combination with table-generating functions such as [`explode`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-explode(array)).  An additional complication in this case is that we need 3 separate occurrences of `LATERAL VIEW` corresponding to the `alpha` `beta` and `delta` arrays, which creates a risk of a full Cartesian product in the result set; every alpha/beta/delta permutation would generate a separate row.

To avoid the Cartesian product, we can use a variant of the function called [`posexplode`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-posexplode), which generates both a numeric index and the data value from the original array.  Then, we can use a filtering condition to make sure we are only looking at rows that matched by position from the original arrays.

**Query**

```
WITH DataTable AS (
    SELECT 'key1' AS key, '<xml><entity><property type="alpha">123</property><property type="beta">abc</property><property type="delta">...</property></entity><entity><property type="alpha">321</property><property type="beta">cba</property><property type="delta">---</property></entity></xml>' AS xml UNION ALL
    SELECT 'key2' AS key, '<xml><entity><property type="alpha">123</property><property type="beta">abc</property><property type="delta">...</property></entity><entity><property type="alpha">321</property><property type="beta">cba</property><property type="delta">---</property></entity></xml>' AS xml
)
SELECT
    key,
    alpha,
    beta,
    delta
FROM DataTable
LATERAL VIEW posexplode(xpath(xml, 'xml/entity/property[@type="alpha"]/text()')) xml_alpha AS pos_alpha, alpha
LATERAL VIEW posexplode(xpath(xml, 'xml/entity/property[@type="beta"]/text()')) xml_beta AS pos_beta, beta
LATERAL VIEW posexplode(xpath(xml, 'xml/entity/property[@type="delta"]/text()')) xml_delta AS pos_delta, delta
WHERE pos_alpha = pos_beta
AND pos_beta = pos_delta
;
```

**Result Set**

```
    key alpha   beta    delta
0   key1    123 abc ...
1   key1    321 cba ---
2   key2    123 abc ...
3   key2    321 cba ---
```

If further customization is required, then you might consider writing your own custom [UDTF](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/DeveloperGuide+UDTF) that generates the rows exactly as you need them.

Comment: Thanks Chris.  Your answer is both correct, and educational.  Extremely helpful!  Now I'm struggling with trying to put together an OUTER view of this somehow, as not every entity has, for example, the "beta" property, and I'd like a NULL in the beta column in that case.   I'll play with it some more, and post a different question if I cant figure it out.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Ckratide , glad to hear this helped!  It sounds like you might be on a path where you need more custom logic.  I edited the answer to say that you might want to consider writing your own custom UDTF.  https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/DeveloperGuide+UDTF